# How to highlight a source node and all its target nodes and corresponding links in d3 hierarchical edge bundling

Tags: d3.js

I am a beginner in d3 JS. I have created a d3 hierarchical edge bundling visualization.Now i am trying to do this: whenever i move mouse over any node(mouse-over event) ,all its target nodes and the corresponding links must be highlighted.How to do this?
My current code is:

```
<html>
    <head>

        <style>
            .node {
              font: 11px "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
            }
            .link {
              stroke: steelblue;
              stroke-opacity: .4;
              fill: none;
            }
        </style>

    </head>
    <body>
            <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
            <script>
            var classes=[
{"name":"a","size":3938,"imports":["b","f"]},
{"name":"b","size":3938,"imports":[]},
{"name":"c","size":3938,"imports":["a"]},
{"name":"d","size":3938,"imports":[]},
{"name":"e","size":3938,"imports":[]},
{"name":"f","size":3938,"imports":[]}


];
                    var diameter = 960,
                        radius = diameter / 2,
                        innerRadius = radius - 120;
                    var cluster = d3.layout.cluster()
                        .size([360, innerRadius]);

                    var bundle = d3.layout.bundle();

                    var line = d3.svg.line.radial()
                        .interpolate("bundle")
                        .tension(.85)
                        .radius(function(d) { return d.y; })
                        .angle(function(d) { return d.x / 180 * Math.PI; });

                    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                        .attr("width", diameter)
                        .attr("height", diameter)
                      .append("g")
                        .attr("transform", "translate(" + radius + "," + radius + ")");



                      var nodes = cluster.nodes(packageHierarchy(classes)),
                          links = packageImports(nodes);

                      svg.selectAll(".link")
                          .data(bundle(links))
                        .enter().append("path")
                          .attr("class", "link")
                          .attr("d", line);

                      svg.selectAll(".node")
                          .data(nodes.filter(function(n) { return !n.children; }))
                        .enter().append("g")
                          .attr("class", "node")
                          .attr("transform", function(d) { return "rotate(" + (d.x - 90) + ")translate(" + d.y + ")"; })
                        .append("text")
                          .attr("dx", function(d) { return d.x < 180 ? 8 : -8; })
                          .attr("dy", ".31em")
                          .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.x < 180 ? "start" : "end"; })
                          .attr("transform", function(d) { return d.x < 180 ? null : "rotate(180)"; })
                          .text(function(d) { return d.key; });


                    // Lazily construct the package hierarchy from class names.

                    function packageHierarchy(classes) {
                      var map = {};
                      function find(name, data) {
                        var node = map[name], i;
                        if (!node) {
                          node = map[name] = data || {name: name, children: []};
                          if (name.length) {
                            node.parent = find(name.substring(0, i = name.lastIndexOf(".")));
                            node.parent.children.push(node);
                            node.key = name.substring(i + 1);
                          }
                        }
                        return node;
                      }
                      classes.forEach(function(d) {
                        find(d.name, d);
                      });
                      return map[""];
                    }


                    // Return a list of imports for the given array of nodes.
                    function packageImports(nodes) {
                      var map = {},
                          imports = [];
                      // Compute a map from name to node.
                      nodes.forEach(function(d) {
                        map[d.name] = d;
                      });
                      // For each import, construct a link from the source to target node.
                      nodes.forEach(function(d) {
                        if (d.imports) d.imports.forEach(function(i) {
                          imports.push({source: map[d.name], target: map[i]});
                        });
                      });
                      return imports;
                    }
                    </script>



    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you make a function `colorNode`.

The goal of the function is to iterate through all the DOMs and check if the data name is same, using filter. For those filtered node make its style fill red.

```
            function colorNode(name){
              //iterate through all the dom and get the DOM which has the data
              var node = d3.selectAll(".node")[0].filter(function(d){
                return d3.select(d).data()[0].name == name;
              });
              //for the matching node DOM set the fill to be red
              d3.selectAll(node).style("fill", "red");
            }
```

Same for displaying links:

```
            function colorLink(src,tgt){
              //iterate through all the links for src and target.
              var link = d3.selectAll(".link")[0].filter(function(d){
                return (d3.select(d).data()[0][0].name == src && d3.select(d).data()[0][2].name == tgt);
              });
              //for the filtered link make the stroke red.
              d3.selectAll(link).style("stroke", "red");
            }
```

Next on the node configure mouseover event.

```
.on("mouseover", function(d){
                          //first make all the nodes/links black(reset).
                          d3.selectAll(".node").style("fill", "black");
                          d3.selectAll(".link").style("stroke", "steelblue");
                          //color the node which is hovered.
                          colorNode(d.name);
                          //iterate over the imports which is the targets of the node(on which it is hovered) and color them.
                          d.imports.forEach(function(name){
                            colorNode(name);
                            //color the link for a given source and target name.
                            colorLink(d.name, name);
                          });
                        })
```

Working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/hpxWMxYlpYuLwip5fm5K?p=preview).

Comment: @Cyril....Thanks...but what i wanted to do is color all the links connected to it.....ie. for the incoming links and outgoing links both....for outgoing links....we check all the nodes in imports of the source node ...but how we will get the incoming links? I tried d3.selectAll('.link').forEach(function(a){if(a.target===d then)}...but a was returning an array of paths instead of links